# MySQL confused about IN (CONST vs UNION vs SELECT FROM (UNION))

Tags: mysql

Can someone please explain why there is big difference between those queries ?

Results of all of them is exactly same.

Performance of `query 1`: very good, `query 2`: bad, `query 3`: good.

Why in `query 2` select from table `test` (id 1) contain all rows ? And why `possible_keys` not contain `PRIMARY` which is actually used ?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Data:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert1000;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert1000()
    BEGIN
        SET @i = 1;
        WHILE @i < 1000 DO
            INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (@i);
            SET @i = @i + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END
$$
DELIMITER ;
CALL insert1000();
DROP PROCEDURE insert1000;
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `test` WHERE `id` IN (2, 3)
```

Query 1 explanation:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | test  | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 2    | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `test` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3)
```

Query 2 explanation:

```
+------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type        | table      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| 1    | PRIMARY            | test       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 999  | Using where; Using index |
+------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| 2    | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | NULL       | NULL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | NULL | No tables used           |
+------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| 3    | DEPENDENT UNION    | NULL       | NULL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | NULL | No tables used           |
+------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| NULL | UNION RESULT       | <union2,3> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | NULL |                          |
+------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `test` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) AS `derived`)
```

Query 3 explanation:

```
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table       | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref       | rows | Extra                    |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+------+--------------------------+
| 1    | PRIMARY      | <subquery2> | ALL    | distinct_key  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      | 2    |                          |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+------+--------------------------+
| 1    | PRIMARY      | test        | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | derived.2 | 1    | Using where; Using index |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+------+--------------------------+
| 2    | MATERIALIZED | <derived3>  | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      | 2    |                          |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+------+--------------------------+
| 3    | DERIVED      | NULL        | NULL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      | NULL | No tables used           |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+------+--------------------------+
| 4    | UNION        | NULL        | NULL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      | NULL | No tables used           |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+------+--------------------------+
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union3,4>  | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      | NULL |                          |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: My guess - there are different strategies for the optimizer to use when dealing with sub queries. The different syntax in queries 2 and 3 probably prompts different strategies. Even though both queries are similar, different optimization strategies mean different performance. Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html

Comment: @Galz very useful thanks !

Comment: very interesting question. +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Inner workings of the MySQL optimizer...

While `query 2` and `query 3` both require a full table scan (can't use the index), their different syntax makes the optimizer use different strategies.

You can see it more clearly(ish) by running `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...` and then running `SHOW WARNINGS;`.

Here's the extended plan for `query 2`:

```
select `test`.`id` AS `id` 
from `test` 
where <in_optimizer>(`test`.`id`,<exists>(select 2 having (<cache>(`test`.`id`) = <ref_null_helper>(2)) 
                                          union 
                                          select 3 having (<cache>(`test`.`id`) = <ref_null_helper>(3))
                                          ))
```

The optimizer translates `IN` to `EXISTS` and then compares the results of 2 queries `SELECT 2` and `SELECT 3` to the row that is scanned in `test`.

Here's the extended plan for `query 3`:

```
select `test`.`id` AS `id` 
from `test` 
where <in_optimizer>(`test`.`id`,<exists>(select 1 from (select 2 AS `2` union select 3 AS `3`) `derived` where (<cache>(`test`.`id`) = `derived`.`2`)))
```

You can see that in this case the optimizer is running your original `UNION` to create a derived table with the values 2 and 3, and then compares this table once to the data it scans in table `test`.

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciate :)